# recipe for target failed openjdk1.8

Tags: java, macos

When I compile openjdk 1.8 using this command:

```
make images
```

Throw this error:

```
cc1: warning: command line option '-std=gnu++98' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/openjdk8-dev/hotspot/make/bsd/makefiles/saproc.make:123: recipe for target 'libsaproc.dylib' failed
make[6]: *** [libsaproc.dylib] Error 1
make[6]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/openjdk8-dev/hotspot/make/bsd/makefiles/top.make:128: recipe for target 'the_vm' failed
make[5]: *** [the_vm] Error 2
/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/openjdk8-dev/hotspot/make/bsd/Makefile:290: recipe for target 'debug' failed
make[4]: *** [debug] Error 2
Makefile:230: recipe for target 'generic_build2' failed
make[3]: *** [generic_build2] Error 2
Makefile:177: recipe for target 'debug' failed
make[2]: *** [debug] Error 2
HotspotWrapper.gmk:44: recipe for target '/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/openjdk8-dev/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp' failed
make[1]: *** [/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/openjdk8-dev/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp] Error 2
/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/openjdk8-dev//make/Main.gmk:109: recipe for target 'hotspot-only' failed
make: *** [hotspot-only] Error 2
```

OS: Mac OS Mojave

gcc version 6.5.0 (Homebrew GCC 6.5.0_2)

Makefile:

```
#
# Copyright (c) 2012, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
# DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
#
# This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as
# published by the Free Software Foundation.  Oracle designates this
# particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
# by Oracle in the LICENSE file that accompanied this code.
#
# This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
# version 2 for more details (a copy is included in the LICENSE file that
# accompanied this code).
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License version
# 2 along with this work; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
# Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.
#
# Please contact Oracle, 500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065 USA
# or visit www.oracle.com if you need additional information or have any
# questions.
#

# This must be the first rule
default:

# Inclusion of this pseudo-target will cause make to execute this file
# serially, regardless of -j. Recursively called makefiles will not be
# affected, however. This is required for correct dependency management.
.NOTPARALLEL:

# The shell code below will be executed on /usr/ccs/bin/make on Solaris, but not in GNU make.
# /usr/ccs/bin/make lacks basically every other flow control mechanism.
TEST_FOR_NON_GNUMAKE:sh=echo You are not using GNU make/gmake, this is a requirement. Check your path. 1>&2 && exit 1

# Assume we have GNU make, but check version.
ifeq ($(strip $(foreach v, 3.81% 3.82% 4.%, $(filter $v, $(MAKE_VERSION)))), )
  $(error This version of GNU Make is too low ($(MAKE_VERSION)). Check your path, or upgrade to 3.81 or newer.)
endif

# Locate this Makefile
ifeq ($(filter /%,$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))),)
  makefile_path:=$(CURDIR)/$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
else
  makefile_path:=$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
endif
root_dir:=$(dir $(makefile_path))

# ... and then we can include our helper functions
include $(root_dir)/make/MakeHelpers.gmk

$(eval $(call ParseLogLevel))
$(eval $(call ParseConfAndSpec))

# Now determine if we have zero, one or several configurations to build.
ifeq ($(SPEC),)
  # Since we got past ParseConfAndSpec, we must be building a global target. Do nothing.
else
  ifeq ($(words $(SPEC)),1)
    # We are building a single configuration. This is the normal case. Execute the Main.gmk file.
    include $(root_dir)/make/Main.gmk
  else
    # We are building multiple configurations.
    # First, find out the valid targets
    # Run the makefile with an arbitrary SPEC using -p -q (quiet dry-run and dump rules) to find
    # available PHONY targets. Use this list as valid targets to pass on to the repeated calls.
    all_phony_targets=$(filter-out $(global_targets), $(strip $(shell \
        cd $(root_dir) && $(MAKE) -p -q FRC SPEC=$(firstword $(SPEC)) | \
        grep ^.PHONY: | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-)))

    $(all_phony_targets):
    @$(foreach spec,$(SPEC),(cd $(root_dir) && $(MAKE) SPEC=$(spec) \
        $(VERBOSE) VERBOSE=$(VERBOSE) LOG_LEVEL=$(LOG_LEVEL) $@) &&) true

    .PHONY: $(all_phony_targets)

  endif
endif

# Here are "global" targets, i.e. targets that can be executed without specifying a single configuration.
# If you addd more global targets, please update the variable global_targets in MakeHelpers.

help:
    $(info )
    $(info OpenJDK Makefile help)
    $(info =====================)
    $(info )
    $(info Common make targets)
    $(info .  make [default]         # Compile all product in langtools, hotspot, jaxp, jaxws,)
    $(info .                         # corba and jdk)
    $(info .  make all               # Compile everything, all repos and images)
    $(info .  make images            # Create complete j2sdk and j2re images)
    $(info .  make docs              # Create javadocs)
    $(info .  make overlay-images    # Create limited images for sparc 64 bit platforms)
    $(info .  make profiles          # Create complete j2re compact profile images)
    $(info .  make bootcycle-images  # Build images twice, second time with newly build JDK)
    $(info .  make install           # Install the generated images locally)
    $(info .  make clean             # Remove all files generated by make, but not those)
    $(info .                         # generated by configure)
    $(info .  make dist-clean        # Remove all files, including configuration)
    $(info .  make help              # Give some help on using make)
    $(info .  make test              # Run tests, default is all tests (see TEST below))
    $(info )
    $(info Targets for specific components)
    $(info (Component is any of langtools, corba, jaxp, jaxws, hotspot, jdk, nashorn, images, overlay-images, docs or test))
    $(info .  make <component>       # Build <component> and everything it depends on. )
    $(info .  make <component>-only  # Build <component> only, without dependencies. This)
    $(info .                         # is faster but can result in incorrect build results!)
    $(info .  make clean-<component> # Remove files generated by make for <component>)
    $(info )
    $(info Useful make variables)
    $(info .  make CONF=             # Build all configurations (note, assignment is empty))
    $(info .  make CONF=<substring>  # Build the configuration(s) with a name matching)
    $(info .                         # <substring>)
    $(info )
    $(info .  make LOG=<loglevel>    # Change the log level from warn to <loglevel>)
    $(info .                         # Available log levels are:)
    $(info .                         # 'warn' (default), 'info', 'debug' and 'trace')
    $(info .                         # To see executed command lines, use LOG=debug)
    $(info )
    $(info .  make JOBS=<n>          # Run <n> parallel make jobs)
    $(info .                         # Note that -jN does not work as expected!)
    $(info )
    $(info .  make test TEST=<test>  # Only run the given test or tests, e.g.)
    $(info .                         # make test TEST="jdk_lang jdk_net")
    $(info )

.PHONY: help
```

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/manasthakur/jdk-tips/wiki/Building-OpenJDK-8-on-Mac-OS-X-Yosemite helps - it mentions that you should use an older xcode because it has an older GCC which is required (newer xcode uses llvm-clang).

Answer (score 0):

The GNU version of make on Solaris is `gmake`. Try that instead of `make`.